# Why aren't script tags executed?

Tags: meteor

I was trying to include the Google Plus One button in a [Meteor app for collaborative sketching](http://gosketch.meteor.com) and I noticed that the `script` tags inside templates are not executed.

```
<template name="gplus">
    <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
    <div class="g-plusone" data-href="{{url}}"></div>

    <!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Google Plus button");
        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script');
            po.type = 'text/javascript';
            po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
    </script>
</template>
```

I got the button to work by moving the script to a separate JavaScript file, but I still wonder why the inline-script didn't work.

I see the script tag on the console, but the script itself doesn't run. How does Meteor do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor just inserts the contents of the gplus template into the DOM, so of course nothing happens because there is no script execution when elements are added to the DOM.

To fix this you can create a .js file and put it in the client folder, which Meteor will automatically include and execute for you (as well as minify in production).

Comment: I was under the impression that scripts inserted into the DOM are automatically executed by the browser, upon insertion. Isn't that so? Can you suggest anything for further reading on this topic?

Comment: Meteor does some other stuff than just a basic script node append operation on the DOM. Template files are converted into a Javascript string and then executed within a different function scope to preserve reactivity. As such, normal script insertion can't be relied upon, which is why the rendered event handler is offered so you can execute script after insertion (for instance). In your case, you probably want your plusone code to be available on the page anyway so I recommend just separating it into its own file.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know _how_ it does this? I mean the client-side JavaScript involved?

Comment: Meteor has a templating system called Spark. You can read the source code for how it parses .html templates and handles them here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/templating/html_scanner.js

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do to load the Google +1 Button in my application:

#### 1. Add the JS library between the `<head>` tag of your application.

```
<head>
  <!-- Load JS Library -->
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
```

#### 2. Insert the +1 Button.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div data-href="https://hackisition.com/" data-size="medium" class="g-plusone"></div>
</template>
```

#### 3. Render the Button.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
  return gapi.plusone.go();
};
```